# Bind ComboBox to Tables of Access Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I have an access database with multiple tables. On a windows form application I have a gridview which displays the columns of one table. However I would like to add a combobox on the application, which would allow me to switch between the tables by selecting the respective table names in the combobox. The gridview should then update with data accordingly. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve list of table using below query,

```
SELECT * FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0;
```

with the above query bind the table names to dropdown.

And in the change event of dropdown, write a select statement to selected table  and extract the column names as follow,

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=MyDB.accdb")

    con.Open()
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable",con)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)

    For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        Dim columnName = column.ColumnName
    Next
```